# Do different dishes give more cooking EXP?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I'm trying to max out the party's stats. I rubber-banded my controller while I was at work and maxed Gladiolus' Survival stat. Now I'm working on Ignis' Cooking stat. When setting up camp, does it matter what dish I have him cook, in terms of EXP gained? Do dishes with rarer ingredients award more EXP?

Comment: I believe I saw a tooltip or something that said the more difficult dishes give more XP. I'm not sure exactly how you measure but certainly I would expect the dishes you pick up later or have rarer ingredients to give more benefit than the starting ones. Not got an authoritative reference or even first hand experience so comment rather than answer.

Comment: > I rubber-banded my controller while I was at work and maxed Gladiolus' Survival stat  You goddam genius. Back on topic I second what @Chris said. I'm pretty sure I saw that tooltip also.

Comment: @BigTallJosh, it wasn't my idea. I'd read a couple threads that suggested it but I refused to do it for a while. I just got sick of running. I got about halfway to 8 Survival fairly, for the record!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually quite hard to find any information on the amount of XP that each dish gives.  [From one site](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/final-fantasy-15-cooking-guide/), it says that it appears to be random, no matter the rarity or difficulty of the dish.

> It seems to be random on which meal gives the most EXP, I created a hard one and got a little bit and a medium one and got almost a full level.

A [video](https://youtu.be/pPcilgSaL9Y?t=2m17s) and [this guide](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/final-fantasy-15-guide-easy-dirty-tips-get-max-skill-fishing-cooking-survival-more-571902) (which references the video) that I found says that the fastest way is to cook Mystery Meat Sushi.  It requires only one ingredient, it's cheap to make at 100 Gil a Luncheon Meat, and you can stock up on the meat by purchasing it at the general store in Lestallum.  After purchasing some meat, cook at a campfire over and over again.  The video description says it should take about 20 minutes to max out.

Comment: I dont believe the random claims at all, i leveled mine to 10 using the Mystery Meat Sushi method and it seemed to increase by the same amount every camp. It is also a very low level dish, so if the rarity or "level" of the dish matters, i dont think it matters much. The mystery meat dish gave about 1/8 or so of a bar every time at level 9.

Comment: @Mayshar I didn't mean/I don't think the guide meant random each time, but the amount of XP for each dish seems random, as in there doesn't seem to be a correlation as to what goes into the dish determines how much XP is gained.

Comment: Oh, i misread then. I still dont know if its random, more so that the amount of exp doesnt change much between first level dishes and high end dishes. Who knows what its actually calculated on.

Comment: @Mayshar I added the quote in, hopefully this will make it a bit more clearer for future readers.  ☺

Comment: that does help i think. I honestly cant say if its correct still though, without some hands on testing. Id be shocked there wasnt something that determined how much exp each meal gives.

Comment: I don't have the game to test with, but this is what I was able to find out on the internet.  See what you can conjure up!